# Using sendmessage in C# to send keystrokes to a window only works when my preview is over source window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sendmessage

I am creating a "simulation" thumbnail that sends any input through to the window it is previewing, using wndproc and sendmessage.  It works fine when the application I am sending to is displayed underneath my preview, but does not work when sending to a application that is not.

My cords seem fine, I don't think it is that.

It works just fine when the window I am sending to is displayed on the same monitor but is not active (behind stuff).

I tested it with multiple programs, same result.

UPDATE:   After further testing, it is not a problem with monitors.  It only works when the preview is over the source window (even with other windows in between).  Thinking it is some event I didn't pass through.  Something else that is interesting is that when holding mouse down on the part of the preview that works, I can't move to the part that doesn't; I assume it thinks it is the end of the window.

Update 2:  Used Spy++, the messages are exactly the same when it works and when it doesn't.

Code:

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0204 || m.Msg == 0x0205 || m.Msg == 0x02004 || m.Msg == 0x0020 || m.Msg == 0x02A3)
        {
            m.Result = new IntPtr(WindowManagerNativeMethods.SendMessage(this._windowPtr, (uint)m.Msg, (int)m.WParam, (int)m.LParam));

        } else if (mouseMsgsWithCoords.Contains(m.Msg)) {  // mouse messegas where I need to chage the coords

            IntPtr xy = m.LParam;
            double x = unchecked((short)(long)xy);
            double y = unchecked((short)((long)xy >> 16));

            if (m.Msg == 0x0084 || m.Msg == 0x020E || m.Msg == 0x020A)
            {

                x -= this.Location.X;
                y -= this.Location.Y;

            }

            x *= ((double)(this._sourceWindowRext.Right - this._sourceWindowRext.Left) / (double)this.Size.Width);
            y *= ((double)(this._eveWindowRext.Bottom - this._sourceWindowRext.Top) / (double)this.Size.Height);

            uint lParam = (((uint)(ushort)y << 16) | (uint)(ushort)x);

            m.Result = new IntPtr(WindowManagerNativeMethods.SendMessage(this._windowPtr, (uint) m.Msg, (int)m.WParam, (int)lParam));



        } else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Comment: It's considerably easier to use Microsoft UIA to automate other apps (even if they are on other monitors) than to deal with mouse co-ordinates and sending messages via native methods

Comment: I looked into it, it doesn't look like it would do what I want.  I have no knowledge of the underlying window (the one I am sending to) that would allow me to identify what element was clicked.  Thats what I understood looking at [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33049/WPF-UI-Automation) and the microsoft page.  I'm looking to do something similar to [isboxer](http://irc.lavishsoft.com/).

Comment: Microsoft has tools (much like Spy++) that allow you peek at the app in question and show you a window hierarchy to find the element you want or you can use search criteria as per the Codeproject example shows

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to interact with a specific element, I want to transfer the user's action to source window, wherever they clicked.  So I would have to look at the source window, figure out what element they would have clicked on, find that element in the source, and then send the event, afaik.  Plus, the layout of the source window will be user dependent.

Comment: Ah...I see.  Well you can still do that.  What's the target app? A game?

Comment: Yeah, most of the time.  I would like to be ale to use it with a web browser and/or mumble (voip) as well.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yes if its a game then typically controls are _rendered_ making UIA not suitable as you mentioned.  I think you are on the right path